# Combining Spring Integration and @ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration

I use Java DSL to build an integration flow like this:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway())
```

I add several message processors that processes a message in the current thread.

Any help how I can implement error handling with a Spring Integration inbound gateway is appreciated.

In particular I would like to know how I can configure the inbound gateway so that it uses Spring controller advice exception handlers defined with the
@ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler annotations.

I don't need a full working example. Just some pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism in Spring Integration to support those annotation mechanisms directly; they are baked into the controller support.

Add an `.errorChannel(...)` to the gateway and handle the errors on a flow starting with that channel (that flow can call any method you want, including the exception handler method, for example).